# Get last element inside new array with key value from Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object where each key have an array of multiple objects. I want to get only the last item from each array.

I tried to push only last element inside a new array but the problem is that now it doesn't say which object belong to which class.

```js
let data = {
        "classA": [
            {
                date: '01-01',
                present: 49,
                absent: 14
            },
            {
                date: '02-01',
                present: 39,
                absent: 24
            },
            {
                date: '03-01',
                present: 35,
                absent: 28
            }
        ],
        "classB": [
            {
                date: '01-01',
                present: 49,
                absent: 14
            },
            {
                date: '02-01',
                present: 39,
                absent: 24
            },
            {
                date: '03-01',
                present: 35,
                absent: 28
            }
        ],
        "classC": [
            {
                date: '01-01',
                present: 49,
                absent: 14
            },
            {
                date: '02-01',
                present: 39,
                absent: 24
            },
            {
                date: '03-01',
                present: 35,
                absent: 28
            }
        ]
    }

    let newData = [];

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        newData.push(value[value.length - 1]);
    }

    console.log(newData);
```

Is there anyway to push class name inside each object and get result something like this.

```
[
  {
    "class": "ClassA",
    "date": "03-01",
    "present": 35,
    "absent": 28
  },
  {
    "class": "ClassB",
    "date": "03-01",
    "present": 35,
    "absent": 28
  },
  {
    "class": "ClassC",
    "date": "03-01",
    "present": 35,
    "absent": 28
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `Object.assign`

```
newData.push(Object.assign({class:key}, value[value.length -1]))
```

But, more a modern method, using [spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) syntax makes it (I think) easier to read

```
newData.push({class:key, ...value[value.length - 1]});
```

```js
let data = {"classA":[{"date":"01-01","present":49,"absent":14},{"date":"02-01","present":39,"absent":24},{"date":"03-01","present":35,"absent":28}],"classB":[{"date":"01-01","present":49,"absent":14},{"date":"02-01","present":39,"absent":24},{"date":"03-01","present":35,"absent":28}],"classC":[{"date":"01-01","present":49,"absent":14},{"date":"02-01","present":39,"absent":24},{"date":"03-01","present":35,"absent":28}]}

    let newData = [];

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        newData.push({class:key, ...value[value.length - 1]});
    }

    console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Exactly as I was going to answer.

Comment: @D.Pardal - I actually changed it using `{class: key, ...value[value.length - 1]}` for more succinct code

Comment: thanks @Phil - I was going to make it more readable  once I added an explanation

Comment: No worries. I just wanted to highlight the interesting part. We all know what the data looks like 

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX .I have been fiddling with it for an hour and finally decided to post here. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = {
        "classA": [
            {
                date: '01-01',
                present: 49,
                absent: 14
            },
            {
                date: '02-01',
                present: 39,
                absent: 24
            },
            {
                date: '03-01',
                present: 35,
                absent: 28
            }
        ],
        "classB": [
            {
                date: '01-01',
                present: 49,
                absent: 14
            },
            {
                date: '02-01',
                present: 39,
                absent: 24
            },
            {
                date: '03-01',
                present: 35,
                absent: 28
            }
        ],
        "classC": [
            {
                date: '01-01',
                present: 49,
                absent: 14
            },
            {
                date: '02-01',
                present: 39,
                absent: 24
            },
            {
                date: '03-01',
                present: 35,
                absent: 28
            }
        ]
    }

    let newData = [];

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
        newData.push(value[value.length - 1]);
newData[newData.length-1].class=key 
    }

    console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
let result = Object.entries(data).map(data => {
    return { class: data[0], ...data[1][data[1].length - 1] };
    });
```